# Disable Add Shortcut to OneDrive to One SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, onedrive

Disable the Add Shortcut to OneDrive to one specific site, so far i do not want to disable for all sites. Below PS will disable to tenant level but i am looking for command for one specific site to disable

```
Set-SPOTenant -DisableAddShortcutsToOneDrive $true
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, we can only disable the “**Add Shortcut to OneDrive**” feature at the tenant level. It is not possible to disable the “**Add Shortcut to OneDrive**” feature for one specific site in SharePoint Online

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com
Set-SPOTenant -DisableAddShortcutsToOneDrive $true
```